# Android - Refresh main content only

Tags: android, view, header, footer, fixed

Still messing with my first android application. Basically, I have a fixed header and a fixed footer with menu icons. It's working kind of well but instead of starting a whole new activity, I only want to update the main content of my application (which I assume would make it 10 times faster). Is that something do-able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually drawing a new layout when switching activities isn't that hefty on the device resources, assuming you're not doing some really heavy things with that layout(animation etc.). You probably want to check out how to set the visibility of views:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29

So if your main content is inside a container, you simple hide that container when fx. your user clicks a button, and show the other content(which was hidden before) instead.

Comment: Well actually it's a news application, so there are like four or five tabs, each contains a ListView or HTML. If it's a listView, clicking on an item takes you the detailed page. In theory it works but I was wondering if there was room for improvement. Your solution might not be ideal in my case.

Comment: In that case take a look at the View.inflate method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to using activities for all pages as this enables the user to go back in the stack using the native back button. If you instead chooses to switch between views in an activity you will also have to manually manage the back button hard key.